# Java mongodb (morphia) ensure unique document

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I've got a task that runs every *n* seconds scanning the file system for new files and storing them into a collection.

I'm not sure of the best way to ensure I don't end up with the same file twice in the database. At the moment I'm taking the files absolute path and checking that against other absolute paths in the database

```
public Movie findByAbsolutePath(String absolutePath) {
    return getDatastore().find(Movie.class, "absolutePath", absolutePath).limit(1).get();
}
```

if this returns null then go ahead and save.

Is checking each file against the database like this the best way to do it? I've tried using the following index annotation but it doesn't seem to work and I end up with duplicates

```
@Indexes(@Index(fields = {@Field("fileName"), @Field("absolutePath")}, options = @IndexOptions(unique = true, dropDups = true)))
```

Is that faster (assuming I can get it to work) than the previous way I'm checking against duplicates?

Comment: you could design a Java Value Object that represents a file. Implement hashcode & equals methods so that duplicate files are easily detected.

Comment: I've already got a file pojo with the hashcode and equals methods if that's what you're referring too? But how would I use that with mongo?

Comment: I think one way is to use your files absolute path as _id, that way it would never be duplicate entries, but you would not want to do it for few reason, other than that I guess you are on right way having a unique index so that any duplicate entries cannot go inside. but then unique indexes are not case sensitive afaik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index isn't working because the uniqueness constraint is on both `fileName` and `absolutePath`.  You'll need the unique constraint on a separate index on `absolutePath` alone.

To do an upsert in Morphia you'd pass an `UpdateOptions` instance to `datastore.update()` as documented [here](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.3/javadoc/org/mongodb/morphia/Datastore.html#update-org.mongodb.morphia.query.Query-org.mongodb.morphia.query.UpdateOperations-org.mongodb.morphia.UpdateOptions-).  `UpdateOptions` has an `upsert(boolean)` that you'd simply pass `true` to.

Comment: Thank you, this is correct. Do you have any insight into what is the more correct way of the two options (or a third?) of making sure there are no duplicates being inserted?

Comment: Honestly, if all you're doing is just logging the path, I'd just attempt the insert and catch/ignore the duplication exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could store file path too in your collection, and have a unique index on file path. When you want to add a new file in your collection, you can do an upsert on file path.

Comment: I'm already storing the path as per my question. How do you perform a upsert with morphia?